# Как перейти на другую страницу после выполнения кода ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Есть форма с регистрацией, оттуда данные с помощью ajax передаются в файл .php для проверки всяких условий(заполненность полей, корректный логин и т.д.). И там же в файле php, если проверки пройдены, добавляется запись в базу. После этого надо перейти на главную страницу.
Вот примерный код файла .php:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['username'])){
    echo 'Заполните поле "Имя пользователя"';
    return;
}//и ещё много всяких проверок
$mysql -> query("INSERT INTO `clients` (`login`, `username`, `password`) VALUES('$login', '$username', '$password')");
$mysql -> close();
header("Location: ../index.php");
?>
```

последняя строка с header почему-то не выполняется. То есть пользователь ввёл данные, нажал "зарегистрироваться" и остался на той же странице. При этом в базе он появился. В форме установлен атрибут "onsubmit="return false"". Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас и php код и html находятся в одном файле. А для функции `header` **[в документации указано](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)**

> **Помните**, что функцию `header()` можно вызывать только если клиенту ещё не передавались данные. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, перед её вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т.п.

Решением может быть парачка вещей:

1. Перенести код php в отдельный файл. Где исключительно код php и ничего больше.
2. Если есть перенаправление - может быть это сделать с помощью *JS*?

---

Кстати, вполне можно было бы увидеть предупреждения в ответе от сервера, если на сервере **[включить отображение ошибок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482)**

Comment: Просто раньше, когда на сайте вообще js не было, это работало, хотя данные тоже передавались. И, кстати, в файле .php и так исключительно php-код)

Comment: Чисто от добавления JS такое не ломается, значит правилось что-то ещё. Например путь до index.php  или в файле есть незаметные символы в начале, но на которые будет выведено предупреждение если включить отображение ошибок

Comment: Можно конечно убрать `"onsubmit="return false""` а в обработчике js поставить `e.reventDefault();` и посмотреть что будет))  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault    ..... только не забыть что `e`  должен быть как параметр в колбэк-функции

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не поменялось

Comment: надеюсь вы писали именно preventDefault)) а то в комментарии написал с ошибкой))  ну тады не знаю. если сейчас удалить js и **ничего больше не менять** и опять сделать чтоб был сабмит - то всё норм?

Comment: Надо попробовать. С этим методом, кстати, уже работал, поэтому написал правильно)

Comment: Написал вот так: window.location.href = "index.php"; Теперь работает, правда, ждёт секунды 2 перед тем как перенаправить. Но уже хорошо)

Comment: Значит запрос долгий.

Comment: Нет, до этого быстро выполнялся

Comment: Ну это уже другой вопрос, возможно, так и оставлю. Спасибо за помощь!